# Create MacOS service using Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, service, osx-mountain-lion

I'm on MacOS Mountain Lion: is there anything like a template to write a service for ML? I use Xcode 4.4.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The service, in generic terms is a *unix daemon*, that is, a binary file, executed in background.

You can use Xcode's "command line" utility template to make such a daemon; you still need some means of staring it. In most of the cases, you'll stick to launchd. Check the man page on launchd.plist(5) for more info.

Ok, on the "other" services thing. That are part of NSService, see the docs on [Info.plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html). You will need to make a "generic" Cocoa application, and then expose its services.

There is also a generic document on services [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000101i).

Comment: I'm talking about services shown in System Preferences under the keyboard shortcuts section

Comment: You can look into any application that supports services, e.g. open up `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/Info.plist` and check the NSServices key. The last link includes description of keys and code snippets required to implement a service.

Comment: I don't think it's all about inserting a key in a plist: there is also  a source code since we're talking about a Mac app... that's why I asked if there were anything like a template

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/Articles/providing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000853-BABDICBI contains a code example for one service.

Comment: I've already read that documentation, but something is going wrong: my service is correctly listed in the system preferences but it never shows up in the "Services" menu in any app. Thank you anyway

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859747/how-do-i-automatically-activate-an-item-in-the-os-x-services-menu

Comment: I found the problem: I did insert the wrong input type. My fault.