# How to enable third party service by default?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

On Snow Leopard the third party services are disabled by default. Is there any way to enable it programmatically? I tried with NSRequiredContext and also by editing pbs.plist programmatically as given in following post 
[How do I automatically activate an item in the OS X Services Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859747/how-do-i-automatically-activate-an-item-in-the-os-x-services-menu)  ,
[NSServices not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370616/nsservices-not-working) but its not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some trouble getting this to work in my application as well. When debugging this try calling `NSUpdateDynamicServices()` when your app launches and make sure you are registering a service provider. The problem could be that your service isn't getting registered at all. You can use terminal to see which services are registered with `/System/Library/CoreServices/pbs -dump_pboard`

Example service:

```
<key>NSServices</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>NSMenuItem</key>
            <dict>
                <key>default</key>
                <string>Open with app</string>
            </dict>
            <key>NSMessage</key>
            <string>processService</string>
            <key>NSPortName</key>
            <string>MyApp</string>
            <key>NSRequiredContext</key>
            <array>
            </array>
            <key>NSSendTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>NSStringPboardType</string>
                <string>NSRTFPBoardType</string>
                <string>NSURLPBoardType</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Comment: I am able to see my service in terminal and also in system preferences --> Keyboard --> services. but it is not checked by default. I want to enable it by default like mail service.

Comment: OK. I updated my post containing an example of a service in my app that is enabled by default.

Comment: its working now with NSApplicationIdentifier key inside NSRequiredContext Dict.